# Lookup document in azure search index using the key

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-sdk-.net, azure-search-.net-sdk

There is this example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lookup-document#example) on how to search a document in the azure search index by passing in the key value. I want to do the same thing using Azure .NET SDK. Is there a way to do this through Azure .NET SDK? I know this is possible through Azure.NET SDK if we make the key searchable in the index. But in my case I am not supposed to make the key searchable.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can find below what you were looking for. There is a `Get` method on `ISearchIndexClient.Documents` property, which does the job.

```
var searchClient = new SearchIndexClient(serviceName, indexName, new SearchCredentials(queryApiKey));

var document = searchClient.Documents.Get<YourDocument>(id);
```

And you need to mark your `Id` with `Key` attribute. This is the minimum required. Please remember about public setters. Otherwise, the document won't deserialize.

```
public class YourDocument
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```